# Missing letters freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

Actually I found an answer a few minutes ago.
But I found something strange.

This is my answer for 'Missing letters' in freeCodeCamp challenges.

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {

var string; 

for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
  if(str.charCodeAt(i)+1 < str.charCodeAt(i+1)){
    string = String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i)+1);
 }
}

return string;

}
```

When I change < operator in if statement into != (not same), it doesn't work!
For me, it seems that != works exactly same as < operator does.
(Because 'not same' can mean something is bigger than the other.)

What is the difference between < and != in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a small defect that works when you use < but not !=.

If you see str.charCodeAt(i+1); this code is checking one spot past the end of the string on the last iteration and will return a NaN result.

If I provide the string "abce" it will check if f is < NaN. I believe NaN can't be compared to f's value so it doesn't go into the if statement. So it will keep the missing letter d that was found in the previous iterations which is stored in your string variable.

However, if you provide the !=, then with the same scenario it knows f != NaN and goes into the if statement. This then overwrite the actual missing letter and fails your FCC test case because it is replacing the missing d with f in your string variable.

To fix your code, simply change the for loop to end one iteration before the length of the string.

```
for (i = 0; i != str.length-1; i++) {
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you believe NaN is greater than f. They can't be ordered I guess. Because they aren't even numbers!

Comment: True, it isn't. But either way it doesn't matter, the condition will fails since NaN can't be compared to a number, so you will get the same result. So you still need to change your for loop condition.

Comment: Do you feel the answer is incorrect, or correct? If you can mark it answer if I have no more questions.

Comment: Thanks, Breakpoint 25! I ran your code on FCC and it passed the challenge. By the way, you mean I should change the loop condition not to compare the string(I mean, ABCs) with NaN?

Comment: yep, there is no so do that check against NaN. So if you remember, the length of an array is always one more than the last index location of an array, so we must perform a subtraction of one from the length to account for that. If you do this, you code is great.

Answer (score 1):

This is my method without using .charCodeAt() function :)

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  var ind;
  var final = [];
  var alf =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
  str = str.split('');
  ind = alf.splice(alf.indexOf(str[0]),alf.indexOf(str[str.length-1]));
  for(var i=0;i<ind.length;i++){
    if(str.indexOf(ind[i]) == -1){
      final.push(ind[i]);
    }
  }
  if(final.length != 0){
    return final.join('');
  }
  return;
}

fearNotLetter("bcef");
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
function fearNoLetter(str){
    var j= str.charCodeAt(0);
    for(var i=str.charCodeAt(0); i<str.charCodeAt(str.length-1); i++){
        j = str.charCodeAt(i - str.charCodeAt(0));
        if (i != j){
            return String.fromCharCode(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  let y = 0;
  for (let i = str.charCodeAt(0); i < str.charCodeAt(str.length - 1); i++) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(y) != i) {
      return String.fromCharCode(i);
    }
    y++;
  }
  return;
}
console.log(fearNotLetter("ace"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  let alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  let alphabet = []
  for(let j = 0; j< alpha.length; j++){
    alphabet.push(alpha[j])
  }
  if (alphabet.length == str.length){
    let result = undefined;
    return result
  }else{
      const start  =alphabet.indexOf(str[0])
      let end = (str.length)-1
      const stop  = alphabet.indexOf(str[end])
      const finish = alphabet.slice(start,stop)


      let result = finish.filter(item => !finish.includes(item) || !str.includes(item))
      result = String(result)
      return  result
  }
  return result
}


console.log(fearNotLetter("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));
```